# function application and mapping using axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading data analysis using python. I have following code. To my knowledge axis 0 means row wise and axis 1 means column wise. Below out put we are doing column wise if we pass axis 0

```
>>> frame
        b   d   e
Utah    0   1   2
Ohio    3   4   5
Texas   6   7   8
Oregon  9  10  11

>>> series = frame['d']
>>> series
Utah       1
Ohio       4
Texas      7
Oregon    10
Name: d, dtype: int32
>>> 
>>> 
>>> frame.sub(series, axis=0)
        b  d  e
Utah   -1  0  1
Ohio   -1  0  1
Texas  -1  0  1
Oregon -1  0  1
```

Anothere question

```
In [158]: frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'),
                        .....: index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
In [159]: frame In [160]: np.abs(frame)
Out[159]: Out[160]:
           b       d        e                 b        d        e
Utah -0.204708 0.478943 -0.519439    Utah 0.204708 0.478943 0.519439
Ohio -0.555730 1.965781 1.393406     Ohio 0.555730 1.965781 1.393406
Texas 0.092908 0.281746 0.769023     Texas 0.092908 0.281746 0.769023
Oregon 1.246435 1.007189 -1.296221   Oregon 1.246435 1.007189 1.296221
```

Another frequent operation is applying a function on 1D arrays to each column or row.DataFrame’s apply method does exactly this:

```
In [161]: f = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()
In [162]: frame.apply(f) In [163]: frame.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[162]:                 Out[163]:
b 1.802165                Utah 0.998382
d 1.684034                Ohio 2.521511
e 2.689627                Texas 0.676115
Oregon 2.542656
```

Here too we are specifying axis 0 which is by default row but here we are calculating function on column wise. I am confused Kindly explain.

Comment: If check docs, `axis : {0, 1, ‘index’, ‘columns’}` means `axis to match Series index on`, [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If check [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) (also [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), 
[`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), 
[`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)):

> **axis** : {0, 1, ‘index’, ‘columns’}
>   For Series input, axis to match Series index on

Check this samples:

```
print (frame)
       b   d   e
Utah    0   1   2
Ohio    3   4   5
Texas   6   7   8
Oregon  9  10  11

series1 = frame['d']
series2 = frame.loc['Texas']

#series is matched index - axis=0
print (frame.sub(series1, axis=0))
        b  d  e
Utah   -1  0  1
Ohio   -1  0  1
Texas  -1  0  1
Oregon -1  0  1

#series is matched columns - axis=1
print (frame.sub(series2, axis=1))
        b  d  e
Utah   -6 -6 -6
Ohio   -3 -3 -3
Texas   0  0  0
Oregon  3  3  3
```

You can also check [matching-broadcasting-behavior](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) or [this very nice explanation of broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc).